# Postgres Create table is hanging for 2 days

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

We are running a database that nearly 11 TB. We are using PostgresQL 9.5. 
After the hard restart in adding new replica we are facing the issues that we can't create new table most of indexes are corrupted.
We can't kill the process that running create table the only thing I could do is restart the database.  I tried to insert new data it's working. Only create table having issue.

Do you know what's the possible reason could lead into that?

Updated.
add pg_activity
[image]

Comment: Check `pg_stat_activity` if that process is waiting for someting

Comment: It's only showing that create table command is running.